# Converting portable to .Net Standard builds locally but not using Team Build

Tags: tfsbuild, .net-standard

I am having problem converting my Portable C# projects to .Net Standard 2.0.

I have followed the method outlined by Adam Pedley in [Upgrade PCL to .NET Standard Class Library](https://xamarinhelp.com/upgrade-pcl-net-standard-class-library/) and finally got everything working locally. However, when queuing on our build server I am faced with the following error:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(323,5): error : Assets file 'D:\Builds\Agent-57-01_work\11\s\MyProject\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [D:\Builds\Agent-57-01_work\11\s\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]

Our build servers are running agent version 2.120.2 and have Visual Studio 15.4.5. installed.

Comment: Does your build include a NuGet restore or does your MSbuid call include a `/restore` argument?

Comment: @MartinUllrich We had a NuGet Installer task set to version 3.0.0 of NuGet. Changing it to 4.0.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the latest NuGet (you can try **Nuget Version 4.3.0**) to restore the packages.

If you are using VSTS, then you can use **NuGet Tool Installer** to install Nuget Version 4.3.0.

For TFS on-premise, just follow below workaround: (See [Using the latest NuGet in your build](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/09/29/using-the-latest-nuget-in-your-build/) for details.)

> Because the NuGet Tool Installer is not available in TFS versions
>   prior to TFS 2018, there is a recommended workaround to use versions
>   of NuGet > 4.0.0 in Team Build.
>
> 1. Add the task, if you haven’t already. If you have a “NuGet Restore”
>      step in the catalog (it may be in the Deprecated tasks section),
>      insert it into your build. Otherwise, insert a “NuGet” step.
> 2. For your
>      NuGet/NuGet Installer step, use the version selector under the task
>      name to select version “0.*”.
> 3. In the Advanced section, set the NuGet
>      Version to “Custom” and the Path to NuGet.exe as
>      **$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\nuget.exe**
> 4. Before your NuGet step, add a
>      “PowerShell” step, select “Inline Script” as the Type, enter this
>      PowerShell script as the Inline Script, and enter “4.3.0” (or any
>      version of NuGet from this list) as the Arguments.

Also reference below threads:

- [Use VSTS to build a solution with VSTS Packages and old style csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155449/use-vsts-to-build-a-solution-with-vsts-packages-and-old-style-csproj)
- [NuGet Restore task fails for .Net Core project migrated with VS
  2017](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3762)

Comment: @Tore Østergaard Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: We had a NuGet Installer task in the build set to version 3.3.0 of NuGet. Changing that to 4.0.0 fixed the issue for that build. I am currently investigating a similar issue in another build that does not seem to use the NuGet Installer task.